# How to exclude data based on date?

Tags: r, date

I want to exclude data before today and after 2 weeks from today. I currently have data like this.
For example today is 01/09/19

```
promo   date    item   discount   stock  stock/day
   a    30/08/19   ax      15%       200     50
   a    31/08/19   ax      15%       200     50
   a    01/09/19   ax      15%       200     50
   a    02/09/19   ax      15%       200     50
   a    30/08/19   bx      15%       200     50
   a    31/08/19   bx      15%       200     50
   a    01/09/19   bx      15%       200     50
   a    02/09/19   bx      15%       200     50
   a    27/08/19   cx      25%       200    200 
   a    27/08/19   dx      15%       200    200
   b    03/09/19   ex      15%       200     25
   b    04/09/19   ex      15%       200     25
   b    09/09/19   ex      15%       200     25
   b    10/09/19   ex      15%       200     25
   b    15/09/19   fx      15%       200    200
   b    16/09/19   fx      15%       200    200
   b    21/09/19   fx      15%       200    200
   b    22/09/19   fx      15%       200    200
   b    25/09/19   fx      15%       200    200
```

so the data will be excluded and the final data will be looked like this.

```
promo   date    item   discount   stock  stock/day
   a    01/09/19   ax      15%       200     50
   a    02/09/19   ax      15%       200     50
   a    01/09/19   bx      15%       200     50
   a    02/09/19   bx      15%       200     50
   b    03/09/19   ex      15%       200     25
   b    04/09/19   ex      15%       200     25
   b    09/09/19   ex      15%       200     25
   b    10/09/19   ex      15%       200     25
```

how to do this? thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 2):

First convert the `date` into standard format, then keep only those rows which are in range

```
todays_date <- as.Date("01/09/19", "%d/%m/%y")
df$date1 <- as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%y")
df[df$date1 >= todays_date & df$date1 < (todays_date + 14), ]

#   promo     date item discount stock stock.day      date1
#3      a 01/09/19   ax      15%   200        50 2019-09-01
#4      a 02/09/19   ax      15%   200        50 2019-09-02
#7      a 01/09/19   bx      15%   200        50 2019-09-01
#8      a 02/09/19   bx      15%   200        50 2019-09-02
#11     b 03/09/19   ex      15%   200        25 2019-09-03
#12     b 04/09/19   ex      15%   200        25 2019-09-04
#13     b 09/09/19   ex      15%   200        25 2019-09-09
#14     b 10/09/19   ex      15%   200        25 2019-09-10
```

You can remove `date1` column if not needed later.

---

If you prefer chains and packages we can also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date1 = dmy(date)) %>%
  filter(date1 >= todays_date & date1 < (todays_date + 14))
```

Comment: actually the today's date are always update according to the day the script is accessed. How to make the today's date update-able?

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto if `todays_date` is always current day you can replace first line with  `todays_date <- Sys.Date()` which will give you todays date and then run rest of the lines as it is.